# Navigation Bar doesn't increase height when UISearchBar is embedded with largest text size in iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I am supporting `DynamicType` in my application. In one of my search screen I have `UISearBar` set as `navigationItem.titleView`. It works fine when text size is normal. But when we increase text size to largest from `Accessibility -> Display & Text Size -> Larger text (on)`, Search bar increase size but not Navigation bar.

This works fine in iPhone, if you increase Text size in iPhone Navigation bar height is also changing accordingly.

Is there any solution

**Code**

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds)
searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
searchBar.delegate = self
navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```

[image: SearchBar in navigation bar]